# Matlab: replace value in a matrix with specific conditions

Tags: matlab, matrix

I want to replace some values of `1` in the matrix `M`, according to the following:

M is a matrix that contains only the values `0`,`1` and `2`:

```
 M = [2  0  1  0  1  2  0  0  0  0
      1  0  0  2  0  0  0  1  0  0 
      0  1  0  0  2  0  2  1  0  0
      0  1  1  2  0  0  0  0  1  0
      0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  1]

max=( 2  1  1  2  2  2  2  1  1  1 )
```

max is the maximum values for each column.

I am only interested by the columns of the matrix `M` whose `max` is `1`

For a given column with `max = 1`, I consider successively one value `1` of this column; I consider only the value `1`  that are in the presence of a value `2` on the same line.

So for a given value `1`, I check if there is another value `1` on the same column whose line does not contain any `2`. if so, I replace the first `1` by `5`. if not, I replace the `1` by `-5`

example:

```
max(3)=1
```

`M(1,3)=1, M(4,3)=1` and `M(5,3)=1`.

Here, for the third column, I consider only `M(1,3)=1` and `M(4,3)=1`. For `M(5,3)=1`, there is no `2` on the 5th line.

So, for M(1,3)=1 (the same for M(4,3)=1) I check if there is another value `1` on the same column whose line does not contain any `2`! in this cas,`M(5,3)=1` satisfies this condition for `M(1,3)=1` and `M(4,3)=1`. I replace `1` by `5`, and I will have `M(1,3)=5` and `M(4,3)=5`

I do the same with the other columns when `max(k)=1`.

in the end, I want to get the result:

```
     M = [2   0   5   0   1   2   0   0   0   0
          1   0   0   2   0   0   0  -5   0   0 
          0  -5   0   0   2   0   2  -5   0   0
          0  -5   5   2   0   0   0   0   5   0
          0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   1]
```

Comment: Did you try to implement this yourself? If yes, how, and where did you get stuck?

Comment: @A.Donda: I tried with loops, but I want to know if there is a method without loop!!

Comment: Your examples are contradictory.  If I understand your language, you are first searching for rows that only contain 1s.  Next, for any column that only contains 1s, you look at each location and scan the corresponding row that the 1 is in.  If the row contains a 2, you mark it by 5, but if it doesn't, you mark by -5.  If you look at the third column, the first row contains a 2 so that should be marked with a -5.  Same with the fourth row of the third column.  Your explanation is contradictory.... and so I don't understand what you're after.  I really don't get what you're solving.

Comment: @rayryeng: "So for a given value 1, I check if there is another value 1 on the same column whose line does not contain any 2. if so, I replace the first 1 by 5. if not, I replace the 1 by -5". The first row contains a 2 but the 5th row doesn't contain any 2! Sorry for my language!

Comment: OK, but you're not replacing all of the 1s in a column.  If you look, the last row remains the same.  Should we also leave the row of 1s that don't contain any 2s alone?  What if you have more than one situation like this?  What if we had the last row repeated?

Comment: @rayryeng: in fact, the Matrix M represent a combination of five vectors, there will be no repetition, and each vector is trying to partially replace the zeros of the other vectors. On the 5th line I did not relace any 1, because for me that line is defined by the fact that there are no 2!

Comment: @bzak - ok so no repeats.  What if your last rows of your matrix were something like this: `[0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   1   1]` and `[0   0   1   1   1   1   0   0   1   1]`.  This is not a repeat of the last row, but the third column has two rows where there is no 2.... so would these two rows still stay as 1 in the third column?

Comment: @rayryeng: yes, nothing will change!

Comment: @bzak Perhaps the simplest way to convey what you're trying to do would be to show us the code you wrote using loops, assuming it achieves your goals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
maxM=max(M)        % never give a variable name of function (like just 'max')
MM=M(:,maxM==1);
maxM2=max(M,[],2);
rows2=MM(maxM2==2,:)*5;
rows1=MM(maxM2~=2,:);

rows2(:,~sum(rows1,1))=-rows2(:,~sum(rows1,1));
MM(maxM2==2,:)=rows2;
M(:,maxM==1)=MM;
```

Comment: ??? Error: Line: 45 Column: 39
Unbalanced or unexpected parenthesis or bracket. ??? Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in ==> at 42
rows2=MM(maxM2==2);

Comment: OK, I removed, checked, and fix it. I think now it's perfect.

Answer (score 0):

```
 M = [2  0  1  0  1  2  0  0  0  0
      1  0  0  2  0  0  0  1  0  0 
      0  1  0  0  2  0  2  1  0  0
      0  1  1  2  0  0  0  0  1  0
      0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  1  1];

  max_C = max(M,[],1);
  max_R = max(M,[],2);

  q = size(M,2);

  for i=1:q
      if max_C(i)==1
          One_index = find(ismember(M(:,i),1));
          p1 = size(One_index,1);

          x=0;

          for j=1:p1
              if max_R(One_index(j))==1
                  x=x+1;
              end
          end

          if x>0
              for j=1:p1
                  if max_R(One_index(j))==2
                      M(One_index(j),i)=5;
                  end
              end
          else
              for j=1:p1
                  if max_R(One_index(j))==2
                     M(One_index(j),i)=-5;
                  end
              end
          end
      end
  end
```